# Outlook would not set up Exchange account

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange

I have Outlook 2003 and when i want to setup an exchange account i keep getting an error:

> The connection to Microsoft Exchange is unavailable.  Outlook must be online or connected to complete this action.

Comment: I have the same problem with Outlook 2010. None of the solutions that show up after Googling seem to help.